# How to store an input to an array and display it without using ternary operators instead use a function and the function will be onclick to a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])

  const clicked = () => {
    if (array.length) {
      return(
        array.map(value => <p>{value}</p>)
      );
    } else {
      return (
        null
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={(event) => setArray([...array, event.target.value])} />

      <button onClick={clicked}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Im expecting that there is a function that will be used in the onclick method in a button. when we click the button the (event.target.value) will be display in a paragraph WITHOUT USING A TERNARY OPERATORS. I also expect that ternary operators WIL BE CHANGE TO AN ***IF STATEMENT IN THE FUNCTION.***

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do - but you need two states.

The flow goes like this:

1. When you type in the input box those letters need to be held in state. Every time you change what's in the box the state gets updated. This state is a *string*.
2. When the button is clicked whatever is stored in the input box state gets pushed to the output state. This state is an array (because you want to hold a series of words etc).
3. In the JSX you can have a function call (I've called it `getOutput` that takes whatever is in the output state, `maps` over it, and produces a list of words in the output box.

*Whenever state changes the component is rendered*. This means that the `value` attribute on the input will always hold the current value in the input state, and the output box will always hold the mapped contents of the output state.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Two states - one for the input string,
  // and one for the output (array)
  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');
  const [ output, setOutput ] = useState([]);

  // Amends the input state with the new value
  function handleChange(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  // When the button is clicked add the
  // current input state to the output (array),
  // reset the input state, and focus on it again
  function handleClick() {
    setOutput(prev => [ ...prev, input]);
    setInput('');
  }

  // Creates a series of paragraphs using
  // the output state
  function getOutput(output) {
    if (!output.length) return 'No data';
    return output.map(el => <p>{el}</p>);
  }

  return (
    <main>
      
      <input
        value={input}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Click
      </button>
      
      <section className="output">
        {getOutput(output)}
      </section>
    
    </main>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { margin-left: 1em; }
.output { margin-top: 1em; border: 1px solid darkgray; padding: 0.5em;}
.output p { line-height: 0.8em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: i havent learn use ref so. i quite dont understand. i might need another answer. please other people answer it simple.

Comment: I took out the useRef references. What is it that you don't understand? Have I misunderstood your requirement? Run the code snippet. Did you want something else? @Ibrahim

Comment: I've also updated my notes in the answer @Ibrahim.